# insert text into span class using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have following html structure

```
<a id="myBtn" class="ui-link">
   <span class="number"> </span>
   <span class="button "> </span>
</a>
```

I want dynamically to insert some content into  `<span class="number">`

```
var content = 99;
$('number').html(content);
```

but nothing change. 
So what I need to do insert value into span that resulted node looks like this

```
<span class="number">99</span>
```

Comment: `.number`. That's how you refer to this class.

Comment: When you say `$('number')`, jQuery is literally looking for an element `<number>`

Comment: [Class Selector (“.class”)](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `.` to get class selector. Use `$('.number')`  instead of `$('number')`

```
$('.number').html(content);
```

OR

```
$('.number').text(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

insert text using class

```
var content = 99;
$('.number').html(content);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.number').html(content);
```

You are referring to a wrong element. You can also do this:

```
$('.number').text(content);
```